# Service account SQL database permission to run SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis, database-administration

I have two servers. One of the server has SSIS installed and the other is SQL Database server. The SSIS server access information from the SQL server through a service account. The SQL server service account is provided 'Execute' grant via a role. It also has "db_datareader" role.

In the SSIS, Execute SQL Task is running which are calling stored procedure [Exec dbo.SPNAME ?] . There is only one task which is directly firing one "Select" statement. Due to this statement, I provided "db_datareader" role to the service account.

My issue is, whenever I execute the SSIS package I get the following error:

> Error: Executing the query "Select ?= Value FROM
> dbo.ConfigurationValues WHERE..." failed with the following error .
> "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'ConfigurationValues'
> database 'ColumbusGDPRDeletion' schema 'dbo'. Possible failure reason:
> Problems with the query, "Resultset" property not set correctly,
> parameters not set correctly or connection not established correctly.

If I provide "ddl_admin" role to the service account then there is no error. But why should I provide "ddl_admin" role since I am not performing any DDL operation. Having said that, I have 'TRUNCATE' statement inside my stored procedure. Can this cause any error?

Comment: `TRUNCATE` requires `ALTER TABLE` as a minimum, otherwise `db_ddladmin` can be used (which would allow the `USER` to `TRUNCATE` all tables in the database, among other things), as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions)

Comment: `db_datareader` does not provide stored procedure execute permissions. If the stored proc includes a `SELECT` query, `SELECT` permissions are not needed as long as the objects involved have the same owner (unbroken ownership chain). However, `TRUNCATE` is DDL and requires higher permissions.

Comment: @Thom A -  I am confused with the error message. It is showing the "Select" action is failing. "Select ?= Value FROM dbo.ConfigurationValues WHERE...". This is a normal select statement and no 'Truncate' is fired while executing this.

Comment: You're missing something.  Try to create a minimal repro and you'll find the problem.  If not post it here.  Also prefer using GRANT SELECT instead of the old db_datareader roles.  You can GRANT at the database, schema, or object level.